# Stack corruption with linked list implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, list, linked-list

My program is supposed to take a word from the user (of unknown length) and then create a linked list where each node should contain one character. It works with a pre-declared word, but I am getting a problem if I try to simplify `cin >> word`:

> Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted.

Any help would be welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct slistEl
{
    slistEl * next;
    char data;
};

unsigned l_size(slistEl * head)
{
    unsigned  c = 0;
    slistEl * p = head;

    if (p)
        do
        {
            c++;
            p = p->next;
        } while (p != head);
    return c;
}


void l_printl(slistEl * head)
{
    slistEl * p;

    cout << setw(3) << l_size(head) << " [";
    p = head;
    if (p)
        do
        {
            p = p->next;
            cout << " " << p->data;

        } while (p != head);
    cout << " ]\n\n";
}

void l_push(slistEl * & head, char v)
{
    slistEl * p = new slistEl;

    p->data = v;
    if (head)
    {
        p->next = head->next;
        head->next = p;
    }
    else
        p->next = p;
    head = p;
}

void l_pop(slistEl * & head)
{
    if (head)
    {
        slistEl * p = head->next;
        head->next = p->next;
        if (p->next == p)
            head = NULL;
        delete p;
    }
}

int main()
{
    slistEl * head = NULL;

    char str[] = "abcdefgh"; // pre-declarated word

    //cin >> str;  //program should take word from user

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        l_push(head, str[i]);
        l_printl(head);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What length of word are you typing into the console?

Comment: it crashes with 10 characters, but

there shouldn't be any limitation of lenght for user, actually word is just an expression here, it can be unlimited string of characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `char str[]` is an array created with the correct length for the literal passed to it, and C++ arrays do not expand dynamically.

If I replace the definition of str with: `char* str = new char[256];` then the program executes perfectly (as long as you don't give it more than 256 characters now).

Better method to do this would be to make use of C++, using `getline` and `string`.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(cin, str);

for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    l_push(head, str[i]);
    l_printl(head);
}
```

Alternatively add characters as you read from `cin`, though this doesn't terminate on newlines as I'd expect.

```
char c;
while (cin >> c)
{
    l_push(head, c);
    l_printl(head);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i cannot use string or pre-declare lenght of word (it is an academic problem)

Comment: @JackPatch in which case just read characters from cin directly, I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! it works for me, now i have to just figure it out how to exit this "while (cin >> c)" loop

Comment: @JackPatch look for `\n` as a canary value. `while (cin >> c && c != '\n')`.Unless someone types in a godawful long string the stream will not pass data on to you until someone hits enter

Comment: @JackPatch Ctrl+C was the only method I found (reading cin like this). A better method then is to have a buffer of 256 bytes, and use `cin::getline` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your `l_push`() method, you allocate the new node:

```
void l_push(slistEl * & head, char v)
{
slistEl * p = new slistEl;

p->data = v;
```

Now, a few lines below, we have this:

```
p->next = p;
```

Do you think it makes sense to set the new node's `next` pointer to point to itself?

Obviously not, and that's your problem.

P.S. If the intent of your `l_push()` is to append the next character to the end of the list (you didn't make it quite clear in your question whether this is the case), even after fixing this problem, `l_push`() will not do it properly. You need a completely different algorithm to implement this logic, correctly.

Comment: So the OP has the last element in the list point to the first, then uses that to determine the end of the list. It's odd, but the code runs as expected.

Comment: my intent was that it should work as circular linked list for other purposes

Comment: It's not going to be a well-working linked list, with each node in the list points to itself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it doesn't though, the condition for `p->next = p;` is that `head` is null, which will only happen at the start when the list is empty.